# Stuck with Multi-Client Chat Application

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, socket

I'm trying to make a MultiClient Chat Application in which the chat is implemented in the client window. I've tried server and client code for the same. I've got two problems:
***A.*** I believe the code should work but, server to client connections are just fine but information isn't transferred between clients.
***B.*** I need a way to implement private one-to-one chat in case of more than two clients, I've used a class to store the information of the Socket object returned for each connection being established, but I can't figure out how to implement it.

The ***server code*** is:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class ClientInfo {

Socket socket;
String name;

public ClientInfo(Socket socket, String name) {
    this.socket = socket;
    this.name = name;
}
}

public class server {

private ObjectInputStream input[] = null;
private ObjectOutputStream output[] = null;
private String value = null;
private static ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection = null;

private static int i = -1;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        server = new ServerSocket(1500, 100);
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection from client");
            Socket connection = server.accept();
            i++;
            System.out.println("Connection received from " + (i + 1) + " source(s)");
            //System.out.println(i);

            new ClientInfo(connection, "Client no:" + (i + 1));
            innerChat inc = new server().new innerChat(connection);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in public static void main! >>>" + e);
    }
}// end of main!!!

class innerChat implements Runnable {

    private Socket connection = null;

    public innerChat(Socket connection) {
        this.connection = connection;
        Thread t;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            output[i] = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            output[i].flush();
            input[i] = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the ***client code*** is

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

 public class ChatappClient {

private static int port = 1500;
JFrame window = new JFrame("Chat");
JButton sendBox = new JButton("Send");
JTextField inputMsg = new JTextField(35);
JTextArea outputMsg = new JTextArea(10, 35);
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ObjectOutputStream output;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChatappClient c = new ChatappClient();
    c.window.setVisible(true);
    c.window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    c.run();
}

    public ChatappClient() {

    inputMsg.setSize(40, 20);
    sendBox.setSize(5, 10);
    outputMsg.setSize(35, 50);
    inputMsg.setEditable(true);
    outputMsg.setEditable(false);
    window.getContentPane().add(inputMsg, "South");
    window.getContentPane().add(outputMsg, "East");
    window.getContentPane().add(sendBox, "West");
    window.pack();
    sendBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(inputMsg.getText());
                outputMsg.append("\n" + "Client>>>" + inputMsg.getText());
                output.flush();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                outputMsg.append("Error encountered! " + ie);
            }
            inputMsg.setText("");
        }
    });
    inputMsg.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                output.writeObject(inputMsg.getText());
                outputMsg.append("\n" + "Client>>>" + inputMsg.getText());
                output.flush();
            } catch (IOException ie) {
                outputMsg.append("Error encountered! " + ie);
            }
            inputMsg.setText("");
        }
    });
}

private void run() throws IOException {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", port);
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    outputMsg.append("I/O Success");
    String value = null;
    while (true) {
        try {
            value = (String) input.readObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        outputMsg.append(value + "\n");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: First of all, try to follow the Java conventions: Class names must start with uppercase. Another problem I see your server is receiving connections but it's doing nothing with them. It must read any client message end then send it to the rest of the clients

Answer (score 1):

Currently your `innerChat` `Runnable` gets the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` but doesn't do anything with them.

The client also simply writes `String`s to its `OutputStream`, however it would be more convenient to send instances of a custom Message class, that, aside from the textual message, holds information for the intended recipient e.g. :

- a specific room member (personal message)
- a room (public message in the room)
- the server (a command)
- ...

The server can then decide what to do with each type of message.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I made the necessary changes and I'm working on the client side right now.